# Move files with version history to another site

Tags: site-collection, folder, version-history, document-migration

Is there a way how to move files with folder structure and version history from   one site to another site?

```
/site1/library1/**folder1** -> /site2/library2/**folder1**
```

i.e. folder1 contains 30 files (.docx, .pptx, .xlsx) with version history

When I try File Explorer drag&drop, I'll receive a message `Can't read file from source`.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharegate seems to be the only option how to do this.